Build and Debug cl.exe and includepath
I downloaded vs code from the official website, inside vs code using the winget install Microsoft.VisualStudio.2022.BuildTools --force --override"--wait --passive --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload command.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK" installed the compiler. I rebooted the PC and installed C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin to the path environment variable. error #1 occurs when typing the code, and error #2 occurs when running the code.

[{
"resource": "/d:/программирование/C++/1.cpp ",
"owner": "C/C++: IntelliSense",
"code": "1696",
"severity": 8,
"message": "#include errors detected. Change the includePath. Wavy lines are disabled for this translation unit (D:\программирование\C++\1.cpp ).",
"source": "C/C++",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 117
}]

writes - "Build and debug cl.exe can only be used when running VS Code from the developer's Command line for VS."


I don't understand at all and I'm confused with all this, please send detailed instructions on what I should do to write C++ code in vs code without any problems. I used to use VS 2022, but I didn't figure out how to create a second C++ executable file in one project/repository and run this second file, I created separate projects/repositories, but it's inconvenient
reinstallation, rebooting the PC does not help

To handle multiple executable files in a single project, you can configure multiple tasks and launch configurations in your tasks.json and launch.json files respectively.
For example, if you have 1.cpp and 2.cpp:
tasks.json:
json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build 1.cpp",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cl.exe",
      "args": [
        "/EHsc",
        "1.cpp"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"]
    },
    {
      "label": "build 2.cpp",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cl.exe",
      "args": [
        "/EHsc",
        "2.cpp"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": false
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"]
    }
  ]
}

launch.json:
json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(Windows) Launch 1.cpp",
      "type": "cppvsdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/1.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "preLaunchTask": "build 1.cpp",
      "externalConsole": false,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    },
    {
      "name": "(Windows) Launch 2.cpp",
      "type": "cppvsdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/2.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "preLaunchTask": "build 2.cpp",
      "externalConsole": false,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }
  ]
}

This way, you can select which file to build and debug from the VS Code interface.
